# Bootstrap classes are not working with HTML Controls in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, css

In my MVC project I applied bootstrap classes to the html input controls but it is not working, before that I used html helper `@Html.Editorfor` but experiencing the same issue. My code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<form action="~/EditProfile/PersonalEdit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
 <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />     
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

HTML helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.FirstName,new {@class="form-control"})
```

How can I apply Bootstrap classes and make it responsive?

Comment: AFAIK the second argument of `EditorFor` is not `htmlAttributes`, it is `additionalViewData` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx). If you change it to `TextBoxFor` it may working properly.

Comment: check the bootstrap css and js is places in correct places css in head and bootstrap js is footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double check and make sure you are linking to bootstrap properly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

View the source of this page and check if bootstrap.css is available on the page. Also check in chrome developer tools network tab for the path to css and js files. I should not be returning 404 error.